# How to change topBar corresponding screen in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-navigation, appbar, android-jetpack-navigation, scaffold

I have a Scaffold like this:

```
Scaffold(
   topBar = {
       TopBar(...)
   },
   bottomBar = {
       BottomNavigationBar(...)
   }
) {
    NavHost(...)
}
```

What is the best way to change TopBar when I navigate to another screen?

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible ways to go:

1. Observing `currentScreen` and use `when` inside `topBar` and change it according to that
2. Put `topbar` inside the screen it belongs to.

For me prefer the second one since it's not shared with each other, there's no reason to use ugly `when` statement for it.

Comment: For (2), should I put `Scaffold()` inside each screen? Or, I can use single `Scaffold()`, but create a mutable state of  composable function (the content of top bar), pass that state to and set it from each screen?

Comment: @xierch yes, put `Scaffold()` inside each screen. What u just said is (1) `currentScreen ` which is `mutableState` with a single `Scaffold()`

Comment: Since I use BottomAppBar I already have a scaffold on my main screen, can I nest another scaffold inside the main scaffold to manage the TopAppBar according to the sub screen where I am, or there are some problems doing this?

Comment: if i put top bar for each screen ,the top bar also gets animated while screen navigation,
ex, fadeIn fadeOut animation looks odd on top bar because the top bar almost same for most screens